# Generate m3u8 file with Extended M3U directives by ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am generating m3u8 files by using ffmpeg.

Command is like below:

```
ffmpeg -i sourcefile.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec libvo_aacenc -b:v 128k -flags -global_header -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -f segment -segment_time 4 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list testlist.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts stream%05d.ts
```

This is creating m3u8 files successfully, but it does not add extended m3u8 directives.

So , how to add those directives ?

Thanking in Advance,

Sagar Joshi

Comment: what do you mean "extended m3u8 directives"?

Comment: the generated m3u8 file doesn't contain http live stream tags

Answer (score 4):

According to the [HTTP Live Streaming](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-10) specification, and unless you're using an older version of ffmpeg (I'm using 1.0), the m3u8 file it creates is fine.

Mine looks like this (while ffmpeg is still encoding):

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOWCACHE:1
#EXTINF:8.308300,
stream00000.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
stream00001.ts
```

By omitting the #EXT-X-ENDLIST tag the client should know to reload this m3u8 file for more media. That is outlined [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH101-DontLinkElementID_11). As soon as ffmpeg quits (or I ctrl-c out of it) #EXT-X-ENDLIST is added to the end of the file.